# How would you abbreviate "sixteen dollars and fifty cents an hour"?

Tags: abbreviations

The full sentence is

> Some mechanics are now earning sixteen dollars and fifty cents an hour.

Should I let it be or change it as follows?

> Some mechanics are now earning $16.50.

Comment: Maybe $16.50/hour?

Answer (score 1):

I think "Some mechanics are now earning $16.50 an hour" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the full sentence works, but "$16.50/hr" would also be correct.